# ScalaTest - how can I find out how many times a method inside an eventually block was executed?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm using ScalaTest's `Eventually.eventually` and have configured it so that it tries to get a record every second until the status is complete:

```
Eventually.eventually(timeout(5 seconds), interval(1 seconds)) {
   getItem(recordId).record.forall(
      _.state.contains(Constants.RecordStatusComplete)) shouldEqual true
}
```

I must get the number of times `getItem(recordId)` was called. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean how many times Eventually calls `getItem`?

Comment: yes, I need the number of times `Eventually` called `getItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just counting it? A bit ugly maybe but scalatest doesn't seem to provide you the amount of attempts it made and presumably this is for testing only, so:

```
val count = Iterator from 0
Eventually.eventually(timeout(5 seconds), interval(1 seconds)) {
   count.next()
   getItem(recordId).record.forall(
      _.state.contains(Constants.RecordStatusComplete)) shouldEqual true
}
// count.next() will give you the attempts
```

I could think of other solutions using mocking frameworks etc. but they'll probably turn out fairly similar.